How to cascade AND-OR with OR-AND structure when using Minhash-LSH
I'v seen cascade AND-OR OR-AND structure from
this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UllNthbqHto&ab_channel=LectureArchive
book: http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds/ch3n.pdf
source description
I'm using AND-OR structure Minhash-LSH, what i'm confued is how to cascade two strcture
the video says 4way-AND-4way-OR followed by  4way-OR-4way-AND will consuming 4*4*4*4=256 hashing functions, confuses me either*
